# Translate with symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I create yml translation file in Resources/translation/translation.en.yml
I want translate phrase like

```
translate:
    row: "great"
```

Then i create Resources/translation/translation.fr.yml and write there translation.

```
translate:
     row: "grande"
```

Now i want use it like that, i tried type

```
    {{ "translate.row" | trans }}
```

But in result i have int template `translate.row`. What i do wrong? Please, help

Comment: have you enabled the translator in your configuration (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#configuration)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot clear cache? I once had a situation like this

```
app/console cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

You must active translator in config.yml :

```
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
```

Comment: change your yml file like that :
symfony.great : 'Symfony is great'

Answer (score 0):

When you add a custom "translation" file (name) you have to add the [translation domain](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/introduction.html#using-message-domains) to the `trans` filter.
So in your case just add it like this:

```
{{ "symfony.great"|trans({}, 'translation') }}
```

PS: and remeber to clear the cache! (any time you add a translation key)